# I can't figure out helper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys
I'm new to rails. I made this small test code for learning helper in rails:

apps/helpers/home_helper.rb

```
module HomeHelper
  def show(var)
    yield var
  end
end
```

apps/views/home/index.html.rb

```
<%= show('hello world')%>
```

When I navigate to the url `localhost:3000/home/index` I got nothing in the html source
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things to note here:

```
module HomeHelper
  def show(var)
    yield var
  end
end
```

Firstly you're using `yield` which will pass control to the block given to the method. However, you then call the method without a block:

```
<%= show('hello world') %>
```

If you would have had a block it would have looked something like this:

```
<%= show('hello world') do |v| %>
  <%= v %>
<% end %>
```

This would have output 'hello world' as you expected.

Most like you meant:

```
module HomeHelper
  def show(var)
    var
  end
end
```

This returns the value you're passing in and will output it to the response stream.

While block helpers can often to be useful for drying up your code most of the time you want a [partial with a layout](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/8/3/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-partials-get-layouts).

Comment: Thank for your answer. the part which I did wrong is <%= show('hello world') {|v| print v} %>I shouldn't invoke print method in here, because in erb, the <%= %> print out the value in the browser

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing yield? Go with simple return:

```
def show(var)
  var
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `yield`. `yield` is meant for blocks - did you mean `return`? (it is optional).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the return is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Another (arguably better) option is to set the display text in your controller.

home_controller.rb

```
HomeController < ActionController 

  # Other controller code...

  def index
    @text = "Hello, world!"
  end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= @text %>
```

Comment: I works, and but for now I want to practice to learn helper. Thanks